# How to reconcile that physicists and science educators use the word "theory" incompatibly?

Tags: discussion

[How to reconcile that physicists and science educators use the word "theory" incompatibly?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68102/how-to-reconcile-that-physicists-and-science-educators-use-the-word-theory-inc)

"This question may already have an answer here:
    Is there an alternative to the scientific method?"

I seriously don't understand how anyone could think those two questions are related, other than both being about science.

Comment: Currently just one user voted to close your question as duplicate. You can see who it is in the comments to your question. Why don't you ask that user in a comment what his or her reasons are?